# How to update a combobox getting registry value

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry

How can I get the value from the registry and autofill the fields when the user open the program, 
and also check the box if the value in the registry are 1 or 0 for exemple?

**This is the code for the ComboBox**

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
Select Case ComboBox3.SelectedItem

    Case "Volume 1"
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\VolumeLevel", "00000001", "REG_DWORD")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Volume 1 Enabled")
    Case "Volume 2"
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\VolumeLevel", "00000002", "REG_DWORD")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Volume 2 Enabled")
    Case "Volume 3"
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\VolumeLevel", "00000003", "REG_DWORD")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Volume 3 Enabled")
    Case "Volume 4"
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\VolumeLevel", "00000004", "REG_DWORD")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Volume 4 Enabled")
    Case "Volume 5"
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\VolumeLevel", "00000005", "REG_DWORD")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Volume 5 Enabled")
End Select
End Sub
```

**This is the code for CheckBox**

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\SoundOnOff", "1", "REG_DWORD")
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\SoundOn", "1", "REG_DWORD")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Sound Enabled")
    Else
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\SoundOn", "0", "REG_DWORD")
        objShell.RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\app\Config\SoundOnOff", "0", "REG_DWORD")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("SoundDisabled")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Im trying to do like this, but the fields still blank when I open, that's what Im trying:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox3.Text = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Webzen\Mu\Config\", "ID", " ")
        ComboBox3.Text = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Webzen\Mu\Config\", "UserID", " ")
        ComboBox3.Text = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Webzen\Mu\Config\", "Exe", " ")
    End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `ComboBox.Items.Add` to add your registry values. For details about the ComboBox class, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.text?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: Actually, I have the values in the combobox already, I just want to select the <option> that is active in the registry.
When the user open, the value found in the registry show up as seleced